# Overwrite a file with an edited version in bash

Tags: bash, cat

What's the shortest code that does this? I've been doing something like

```
echo "header" >  tmpfile
cat $file     >> tmpfile
echo "footer" >> tmpfile
mv tmpfile $file
```

.
Is there a more compact way?

Comment: In PowerShell you could do `'header',(gc $file),'footer'|Out-File $file` :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
echo "header"
cat $file
echo "footer"
} > tmpfile
mv tmpfile $file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i -e '1s/^/header\n/' -e '$s/$/\nfooter/' $file
```

**Update**: even shorter:

```
sed -i '1s/^/header\n/;$s/$/\nfooter/' $file
```

**Update**: and even shorter (but must be on many lines as `'i'` and `'a'` commands in `'sed'` must be followed by a `\<newline>`):

```
sed -i '1i\
header
;$a\
footer' $file
```

Comment: Knew it was possible to do in sed, but was unsure of the proper syntax to describe last line. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use a Here document

```
tee > /tmp/otherfile <<EOF
header
$(cat $file)
footer
EOF
```

And then rename.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in `zsh`, but unfortunately not in `bash`.

```
TMPTXT="header\n"$(cat $file)"\nfooter"
echo $TMPTXT > $file
```

or in one line:

```
echo header\\n"$(cat $file)"\\nfooter > $file
```

(I think this should work in `bash` as well, except I have some trouble getting the newlines right.)

**EDIT:**

Using echo -e this also works in `bash` in one line:

```
echo -e "header\n$(cat $file)\nfooter"
```

Comment: Are you sure the 'echo ... > $file' works in all cases, because if the parameter evaluation is done after the redirection, the 'cat' could print an empty file.  I tried it on cygwin and your solution works (parameters seams to be evaluated before the redirection), but is it the same in all shells ?

Comment: `'echo -e "header\n$(cat $file)\nfooter" > $file'` works in cygwin, but `'echo -e "header\n$(cat $file)\nfooter" | cat > $file'` does not...

Comment: This is indeed a valid case, I'm not sure if this would always work. I tried this on my Macbook and it seems to work OK (zsh 4.3.11 on OS X 10.7). A safer bet is using the temporary variable, except I haven't gotten that to work in bash (newlines are dropped with `echo $(cat $file)`).